# How to add metadata and tags to folders in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, metadata

How could I add metadata and tags to folders? I know that I can add metadata and tags to files supported by File Explorer. For unsupported files, I use 
[File Metadata](http://filemeta.codeplex.com/), but it seems not supporting adding metadata and tags for folders. *I'm using Windows 10*.

---

There's [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/406111) that's asking about adding files/folders metadata for Windows 7. My question is asking about adding metadata **as well as tags** specifically for folders on Windows 10.

Comment: @duDE My question is asking about adding metadata as well as tags specifically for folders on Windows 10. Then, my question isn't duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean by tags? I'm not familiar with using tags in the NTFS file system or Windows Explorer, and I've been using these for decades. Also, have you TRIED performing the actions suggested in the other question? What about them didn't work?